# Click button in WebBrowser control vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am trying to click the button highlighted in picture below. The code is from a web page:

[image]

I'm not to sure, but I believe the button is within an iFrame.

I have tried:

```
Dim wrapClick As HtmlElement = Contact.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Btn_WrapUp")
wrapClick.InvokeMember("Click")
```

And:

```
Dim elPoint As New Point(704, 340)
Dim wrapClick As HtmlElement = Contact.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint(elPoint)
wrapClick.InvokeMember("onClick")
```

And:

```
Contact.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Btn_WrapUp").InvokeMember("Click")
```

In all of the above, I have tried 'onClick' and 'Click'.

WebBrowser1 is on a different form.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm I try this with some html in iframe... I see empty iframe (where is html?) and error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Without iframe, InvokeMember works with no errors.

Comment: Ok, I see html in iframe, but have no access to elements. _"Access to frames is complicated by the fact that the managed HTML DOM implements a security measure known as cross-frame scripting security."_ And InvokeMember on element in iframe returns "access denied". See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171715.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So, does this mean it is not possible to click this button pragmatically? Is the any other methods other than InvokeMember I can try? @capricorn

Comment: Please bare in mind I am at a beginner level with vb.net and below that in HTML

Comment: It seems that it is not possible to click a button on a html placed in an iframe. For security reasons. Am afraid that there is no other method. In html without iframe, click works.

Comment: Could I not even execute the 'onClick' command:
"activityHelperObj.WrapUp(); return false;"
or the jQuery using code? Without having to actually click the button. @capricorn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click button in WebBrowser control - working example:

Main file with frame - x.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe width="400" height="300" src="y.html" id="frame1"> </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

File placed in frame - y.html - with submit button:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="...some_action...">
<input type="submit" id="btn"> Submit!
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Button on VB form with OnClick event:

```
Dim Frame1 As HtmlWindow = WebBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames("frame1")
Frame1.Document.GetElementById("btn").InvokeMember("click")
```

VB2010Ex & .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.
I have tried code with action that load other site. Site was loaded in iframe.
Finally success :-)

Comment: Damn, @capricorn, you're good! Worked perfect, thank you very much :D